# Task not found error while using Grunt task runner

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs

I am on a Windows machine and I believe I have installed everything I need to run the grunt task:
`grunt sass`
I have already executed the following commands in my terminal:

`npm install grunt-sass --save-dev`

`npm install time-grunt --save-dev`

`npm install jit-grunt --save-dev`

`npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev`

`npm install grunt-browser-sync --save-dev`

I am getting the following error:

`Warning: Task "sass" not found. Use --force to continue.`

`Aborted due to warnings.`

I have tried every possible solution from other similar posts but to no avail. My `Gruntfile.js` is as follows:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    require("time-grunt")(grunt);

    require("jit-grunt");

    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    "css/styles.css": "css/styles.scss"
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            files: "css/*.scss", 
            tasks: ["sass"]
        },
        browserSync: {
            dev: {
                bsFiles: {
                    src: [
                        "css/*.css",
                        "*.html",
                        "js/*.js"
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    watchTask: true,
                    server: {
                        baseDir: "./"
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    });

    grunt.registerTask("css", ["sass"]);
    grunt.registerTask("default", ["browserSync", "watch"]);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the solution. Make the following changes to the file:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    const sass = require('node-sass'); // add this line

    require("time-grunt")(grunt);

    require("jit-grunt")(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    "css/styles.css": "css/styles.scss"
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            files: "css/*.scss", 
            tasks: ["sass"]
        },
        browserSync: {
            dev: {
                bsFiles: {
                    src: [
                        "css/*.css",
                        "*.html",
                        "js/*.js"
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    implementation: sass, //add this line
                    sourceMap: true,      //add this line
                    watchTask: true,
                    server: {
                        baseDir: "./"
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    });

    grunt.registerTask("css", ["sass"]);
    grunt.registerTask("default", ["browserSync", "watch"]);

};
```